Is it possible to read page table in Linux with unprivileged mode?
this is my very first question in Unix & Linux, I'm currently learning about virtual memory.
I am appreciating this awesome paper drammer (CCS'16). Where it fools the buddy allocator to allocate a page table page in a vulnerable page in Android 6.0.1 (corresponding linux kernel perhaps is ~3.18.10.) with unprivileged operations (since their ultimate purpose is Root Privilege Escalation.).
While, I have no idea how to access a page table page just in user mode. Since we know in virtual memory, the whole virtual memory address will be split into kernel and user space (e.g., the top 1GB/4GB is the kernel space.), where the kernel space cannot be accessed in user mode. And my two corresponding question arouse:

Is page table pages locate in kernel space totally? What i mean is, can we find such a specific page table page, which locate in the user space of a specific process (see a short discussion in this post.)? I hypothesis the answer is no.

malloc will allocate virtual memory in user space, can we allocate virtual memory in kernel space just with unprivileged operations?


Is there some tricky thing, like via DMA, we can read memory in kernel space at our will? Or these is some profound difference between linux and Android? Or I missing something?
Thanks.
